# GLKMathProject gives me estrange numbers

Tags: ios, xcode, opengl-es, coordinates, glkit

I can not get the screen coordinates, I only get big numbers when I use the code below, can somebody tell me why, the position of x, y is in radians, is that a wrong ?

```
float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(_overture),
                                                        aspect,
                                                        0.1f,
                                                        400.0f);
projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(projectionMatrix, ES_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);


GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Identity;
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Scale(modelViewMatrix, 300.0, 300.0, 300.0);

modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateX(modelViewMatrix, 0.296706);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(modelViewMatrix, -0.858702);

_modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

CGSize viewSize = self.view.bounds.size;
int viewPort[4];
viewPort[0] = 0;
viewPort[1] = 0;
viewPort[2] = (int)viewSize.width;
viewPort[3] = (int)viewSize.height;

pos.x = 0.296706; //radians
pos.y = -0.858702; //radians
GLKVector3 coor2 = GLKVector3Make(pos.x, pos.y, 0);

GLKVector3 windowVector = GLKMathProject(coor2, modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewPort);
```

> projectionMatrix 
>      0.818481, 0.000000, 0.000000,  0.000000
>      0.000000, -1.091309, 0.000000,  0.000000
>      0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000500,  1.000000
>      0.000000, 0.000000, -0.200050,  0.000000
>
> modelviewmatrix 
>      196.026169, -66.397179, 217.175415,  0.000000
>      0.000000, 286.891449, 87.711510,  0.000000    -227.098526, -57.312504, 187.460770,  0.000000
>      0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000,  1.000000
>
> _modelViewProjectionMatrix :
>      160.443787, 72.459831, 217.284042,  217.175415
>      0.000000, -313.087097, 87.755409,  87.711533    -185.875931, 62.545647, 187.554535,  187.460770
>      0.000000, 0.000000, -0.200050,  0.000000

Comment: coord2 should be in object space. Not in radians.

Comment: NSLog the projection matrix and the modelview matrix.

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin thanks for your time, I added more code, as a result I get this numbers  windowVector.x = -1725.853271, windowVector.y -9824.593750 what I want to know is where in the window coordinates the x, y radians are.  so how do I know which is the position inside my object space for the x,y radians in order to calculate the window coordinates ??? my object is a sphere with an image in 360 degrees inside, thanks...

Comment: @lead_the_zeppelin should I use  _modelViewProjectionMatrix intend of modelViewMatrix  in the GLKMathProject function ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your camera is at (0,0,0) looking at m41,m42,m43 of your modelViewMatrix and your object's coor2.z = 0. Your are at the center of the object. This might be the problem?

Comment: I don't think so, because if you look at the code I rotate the modelViewMatrix modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateX(modelViewMatrix, 0.296706);
modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(modelViewMatrix, -0.858702); the modelViewMatrix you see is after rotation, the rotation changes only the y,x,z axis and not the camera, thats why the camera is 0.

Comment: @user1241006 can you try it with coor2 = (10,10,10)? just to make sure values are not too high?

Comment: thanks, now is working, the problem was that i was not using the exact coordinates, I tried  coor2 = (10,10,1) and it was working perfect every time I rotated the matrix the new coordinates on the screen were calculated for the point (10,10,1), I left the z value in 1 always and is working perfect,   thanks for your help...